# I want to use "Send to Current Layer", but it's disabled no matter what I do

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers

I want to move the selected groups below to the **Cross Sections** layer.  Drag and drop in the layers tree works, but there are many more paths and groups I need to select, and drag and drop is a hassle when you need to scroll around a lot.  Assume the I need to move an item that's so far away from the target layer that I keep missing the target layer as it autoscrolls.

As you can see the groups are selected and the Cross Sections layer is highlighted, but the "Send to Current Layer" command is disabled.

As a matter of fact, no matter what other layer I click on, Send to Current Layer never gets enabled.  I've never ever seen it enabled.  Is this a bug or am I misunderstanding what the "current layer" is and how "Send to Current Layer" works?

[image]

Comment: The layers panel also shows things that are not layer objects. You can obviously not send items to nonlayers. Anyway its more easy to drag the small colored pip to where you want it to be

Comment: Much faster to merely drag things around in the layers panel. I've never used that specific menu item, ever `:)`

Comment: @joojaa it's impossible to tell from the screenshot but Cross Sections is definitely an empty sublayer, not another type of item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object> Arrange> Send to Current Layer will only send selections to a new 1st level layer and not a sublayer.

Click the Create New Layer button (not the Create New Sublayer button) at the bottom of the Layers Panel. Highlight the newly created Layer. You can then select what you want to move there and the Object> Arrange> Send to Current Layer will work.

Comment: I'm confused, why would it say "current layer" if it would actually send to a new 1st level layer?

Comment: In any case this is a real shame because I was looking for a more convenient way to move items when they're far away from the layer I want.  I remember in Rhino3d it was easy to select objects, right click on a layer, and click a menu item to move the selected objects to that layer.

Comment: @Andy well you can group and collect to layers. If you must do this with sublayers. Not much point in having sublayers though due to the way illjstrator works. Or you can just drag any selected colored pip on the right of your layer or group name and it moves all of them (since the pip is also in the top level layer its guaranteed to be close to your position)

Comment: I agree with Andy, this is just terrible, terrible behavior. I remember how easy it was to use Freehand's paste inside and after all these years Adobe still hasn't managed to implement something as good as that within Illustrator, incredible.